# Catch Cannot read property of null

Tags: javascript

In my application I have a code like this :

```
"docDecesPere": $scope.orphanFatherDocumentUpload == null ?
    (
      res.candidatureSituationSociale != "undefined" ?
      res.candidatureSituationSociale.docDecesPere :
      null
    ) :
    $scope.orphanFatherDocumentUpload.name
```

In some scenarios `res.candidatureSituationSociale` my be undefined so as you can see I have tested it so if its not undefined I'll affect `res.candidatureSituationSociale.docDecesPere` to `"docDecesPere"`, but I'm always getting this error :

```
Cannot read property 'docDecesPere' of null
```

So why I'm getting this even though I had a test on it, and how can I solve it ?

Comment: Maybe you meant `res.candidatureSituationSociale !== undefined` or `typeof res.candidatureSituationSociale !== "undefined"` ?

Comment: Well, if it's `null`, it's indeed neither `undefined` nor `"undefined"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're checking variable as `"undefined"`, which is a string, you have to use `typeof(var)`.

In JS, you can easily check if variable is `null` or `undefined` by doing,

```
undefined || null ? 'true' : 'false'
```

You might want to try your code like this,

```
"docDecesPere": !$scope.orphanFatherDocumentUpload ?
    (
      res.candidatureSituationSociale ?
      res.candidatureSituationSociale.docDecesPere :
      null
    ) :
    $scope.orphanFatherDocumentUpload.name
```

In this case, you have to ensure that `res.candidatureSituationSociale.docDecesPere` is not null.

Answer (score 2):

You are enclosing them in `"` so you need to use `typeof`:

```
typeof res.candidatureSituationSociale != "undefined"
```

For safety, add `null` as well.

```
typeof res.candidatureSituationSociale != "undefined" &&
res.candidatureSituationSociale != null
```

Answer (score 1):

A possibly better way of testing for a variable to be either null or undefined is to test for it being not equal to `null` or `undefined`

```
res.candidatureSituationSociale != null
```

will be true for all `res.candidatureSituationSociale` values except `null` and `undefined`